# About Leetcode question "Linked List Cycle" - Python

Tags: python

I did Leetcode question.
The question is [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/linked-list-cycle/).

And the answer is

```
head = [3,2,0,-4]
pos = 1

class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None

class Solution:
    def hasCycle(self, head):
        if head is None:
            return False
        
        fast = head.next
        slow = head
        
        while slow is not None:
            if fast is None or fast.next is None:
                return False
            
            fast = fast.next.next
            slow = slow.next
            if fast == slow:
                return True
            
        return False
            
s = Solution()
print(s.hasCycle(head))
```

I run it in VScode terminal but
the error happens.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LinkedListCycle.py", line 30, in <module>
    print(s.hasCycle(head))
  File "LinkedListCycle.py", line 15, in hasCycle
    fast = head.next
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'next'
```

I don't know what the 'list' object is.
Why does it occur?

Comment: `head` is declared as a python `list` and it has no attribute `next`.

Comment: A hint: You didn't use the `ListNode` class even once...

Comment: hint 2: `head` should probably be a `ListNode`

Comment: The "'list' object" is `[3,2,0,-4]`, which is not a linked list. You need to create a linked list first. (And the `Solution` class is pointless - you just need the function. You don't need to do Object-Obsessive programming in Python.)

Comment: @molbdnilo The `Solution` class is, from what I recall, a requirement imposed by LeetCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At runtime, Leetcode will provide you with only a ListNode (which is the head of the chain),  the lists contained in the explanations are only a way to describe the content of the chain. They are not what you should use for testing.  You will need to build your own chain of ListNodes based on these lists to perform your tests:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None

values,pos = [3,2,0,-4],1
nodes  = [ListNode(v) for v in values]
for node,nextNode in zip(nodes,nodes[1:]+nodes[pos:pos+1]):
    node.next = nextNode
head   = nodes[0]
```

Now you can uses head to test your solution:

```
Solution().hasCycle(head)
```

*as a side note, you should check for equality between slow and fast at both steps when you advance fast.  Otherwise you risk skipping over the slow iterator and possibly never reach it if there is an even number of nodes in the cycle*

Example in O(n) time and O(1) space:

```
def hasCycle(head):
    tail = head and head.next           # cover case of no list at all  
    step = 1
    while tail and head is not tail:    # check at every step
        if step%3 : tail = tail.next    # advance tail twice as often
        else      : head = head.next
        step += 1
    return bool(tail) # cycle present when tail has not reached end
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your`head = [3,2,0,-4]` is array which is called list in python. And **list** object has no **next** attribute in python.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first create a linked list from your `list` value.

```
def make_ll(lst):
    if not lst:
        return None
    ll = ListNode(lst[0])
    ll.next = make_ll(lst[1:])
    return ll

s = Solution()
print(s.hasCycle(make_ll(head)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could setup your problem like this:

```
lst, pos = [3,2,0,-4], 1

node = tail = None
for i, val in reversed(list(enumerate(lst))):
    head = ListNode(val)
    if tail is None:
        tail = head
    if i == pos:
        tail.next = head
    head.next = node
    node = head

# head is now a linked list with a cycle starting at index pos
```

Unlike similar suggested approaches, this is purely iterative and linear. It also links the last node to the node at the position of where the cycle starts.